# If a number is a square modulo $n$, then it is also a square modulo any of $n$'s factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say we have $a \equiv x^2 \bmod n$. How would we prove that this implies:

$$\forall \text{ prime }p_i\text{ such that }\,p_i\mid n,\;\exists y\,\text{ such that }\, a \equiv y^2 \bmod p_i$$

Comment: Hint: Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: @Henrik: The Chinese remainder theorem is not necessary here, it is just basic properties of modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n$ is a natural number and $a$ and $b$ are integers, when we say $$a\equiv b\bmod n,$$ we just mean that $n$ divides $b-a$. This clearly implies that any factor of $n$ also divides $b-a$, so that if $m$ is any factor of $n$, we also have $a\equiv b\bmod m$.

Thus, if we start with our integer $a$, and there exists an integer $x$ such that
$a\equiv x^2\bmod n$, we must also have $a\equiv x^2\bmod m$ for any number $m$ that divides $n$, and in particular, $a\equiv x^2\bmod p$ for any prime factor $p$ of $n$.

Comment: Thanks. This is so simple, can't believe I was struggling with this.

Comment: Glad I could help! And don't worry, it happens to all of us sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ $ note that $\ a\ $ is a square mod $\, n\iff\ f(x) = x^2-a\ $ has a root mod $\, n.\, $

But a root mod $\, n\, $ of a polynomial $\ f(x)\in \Bbb Z[x]\ $ *persists* as a root mod $\, k\,$ for  $\, k\mid n\,$

because $\ \ f(b)\equiv 0\pmod{n}\ \Rightarrow\ n = jk\mid f(b)\ \Rightarrow\ k\mid f(b)\ \Rightarrow\ f(b)\equiv 0\pmod{k} $

As another example, the linear analog of *square* preservation is *fraction* preservation. For example, if $\ ab = 2k- 1\ $ then, mod $\, ab,\,$ we have $\, 2k\equiv 1\ $ so $\, 1/2 \equiv k,\,$ and this congruence remains true both mod $\,a\,$ and mod $\,b.$

More generally, any solution of an equation in an equational algebraic structure remains a solution in any modular (homomorphic) image of the structure.